# Trying to get to the code lines of a form's module in a remote project

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to list code lines of all procedures in a remote MS Access project. There is no problem with the standard or class modules but when I get to the forms, I cannot access their modules properties.

```
Public Sub TestFrms(MyDataBaseFullName)

  'MyDataBaseFullName should be a valid full name (Path & Name)
  'of an MS Access DataBase mdb or accdb local file
  
  Dim appAccess As Access.Application
  Dim xObj As AccessObject
  Dim xFrm As Form
  Dim xMdl As Module
  Dim i As Long
  
On Error GoTo Error
  
  Set appAccess = New Access.Application
  
  Call appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(MyDataBaseFullName)

  For Each xObj In appAccess.CurrentProject.AllForms

      For i = 0 To appAccess.CurrentProject.AllForms.Count - 1
        'Here I am trying to get to the forms module
        'because I want to lit all its code lines
        
        'I think understand that the AllForms property does not contain
        'a list of all the Forms objects but only a collection of AccessObject
        'but is there a way to get to the Form's module?
        
          'Assuming AllForms contains a collection of forms
          'this next line should work and I could get to the
          'Code Lines of each procedure in that module

''        Set xMdl = appAccess.CurrentProject.AllForms(i).Module
      
      Next i

  Next
  
NormalEnding:

  'Fermer la base de données
  appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
  Set appAccess = Nothing
  Set xObj = Nothing
  Exit Sub

Error:
      'Aviser l'utilisateur
  Call MsgBox("Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")", vbCritical)
  
  GoTo NormalEnding
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a form's module, you need to open the form in design view.

```
For Each xObj In appAccess.CurrentProject.AllForms
    appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm xObj.Name, 1 '1 = acDesign
    Debug.Print appAccess.Forms(xObj.Name).Module.Lines(1, 10000) 'Print the first 10K lines
    'If you want to print all lines with no maximum, use `Module.CountOfLines` to get the count
    appAccess.DoCmd.Close 2, xObj.Name '2 = acForm
Next
```